# How to get id as key and email as its value from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multi-dimensional array like below

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 11,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'email' => 'john@gmail.com'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 12,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
        'email' => 'sally@gmail.com'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 13,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
        'email' => 'jane@gmail.com'
    )
);
```

Now,I want the output as array in form of id as key and email as its value.

```
Array
(
    [11] => john@gmail.com
    [12] => sally@gmail.com
    [13] => jane@gmail.com
)
```

I want short code for it, Not want any lengthy code.

I have tried it with foreach

```
$collect_data = array();
foreach($records as $key=>$data){
  $collect_data[$data['id']] = $data['email']
}
```

Any one know short code for above to achieve my requirement.

Comment: "I have tried it with foreach" - And what went wrong?

Comment: What is wrong with this? The above code is fine.

Comment: Your code is already three lines [one `for` block], I think it is short and expressive enough ^^

Comment: I am trying to do short code as possible, want to know one line code, not want to go for lengthy foreach code.

Comment: No its my just an example, if i got perfect solution then its save my lots of code.

Comment: making this shorter is just silly

Comment: "`I want one line code`" -> that's not how you measure code brevity. If you are reusing this structure a lot, chances are that you should redesign something // wrap it into a reusable function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, You can try php in-build function to sort out your solution

```
$emails = array_column($records, 'email', 'id');
print_r($last_names);
```

You can also refer following link too.

[Php In-build Function (array_column)](http://questionnanswer.com/questions/view_question/88/category_list:2/Get-column-of-first-names-from-recordset)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Just [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) the `id` column with the `email` column, which you can grab with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
$collect_data = array_combine(array_column($records, "id"), array_column($records, "email"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility sake, as `array_column` was introduced in PHP 5.5, consider `array_reduce`:

```
$output = array_reduce($records, function($memo, $item){
  $memo[$item['id'] = $item['email'];
  return $memo;
}, []);
```

I find it more expressive than a `foreach`, but that's matter of personal taste.